# How to redirect the ansible execution output to a log file on remote host to specified location

Tags: ansible

I want store the execution of my playbook on remote host in a specified directory.

For example  below playbook I want the entire output of execution on remote host where the below tasks are being executed.

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  - name: copy the svn text file to {{tgt1.stdout}} folder
    copy:
    src: /u01/checkout/
    dest: /u01/checkout/
    follow: true
    mode: 0755
  - name: commit the changes
    shell: svn ci --username bamboo --password bamboo 
    args:
    chdir: /checkout/checkout/